# importing SQL Server .bacpac file

Tags: sql-server, bacpac

I've been trying (and failing) to import a SQL .bacpac file to SQL 2014 Express. Does anyone know if it's even possible to import these to Express?  I haven't found anything online saying otherwise, but thinking of just getting the developer edition to try that instead.  For info here is the error I get

Internal Error. The database platform service with type Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Sql.Sql130DatabaseSchemaProvider is not valid. You must make sure the service is loaded, or you must provide the full type name of a valid database platform service. (Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Sql)

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The '130' database level is SQL 2016, but you are attempting to restore it to a SQL 2014 database. SQL Server backups have never been backward compatible.

Comment: You're correct about backup files not being backward compatible.  However, you're incorrect about bacpac files.  No restriction exists that prevents a bacpac file from being imported to any server version -- except the fundamental requirement that the version of sqlpackage.exe (or the Data-Tier Application Framework) being used supports the file version of the bacpac file.

Comment: This link should help  http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/bradleyschacht/2016/09/13/importing-a-bacpac-to-sql-server/

Answer (score 4):

This did not work because the version of SqlPackage.exe, SSMS or the Data-Tier Application Framework that you're using to import the bacpac file to your server is too old and therefore doesn't know about SQL Server 2016.  If you install the latest version of SSMS (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms) you should be able to import that bacpac file.

However -- do note that if your bacpac file contains any object that isn't supported in SQL Server 2014 (for example, a temporal table), then the import operation will fail.